# Month difference between two dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer the below examples and kindly let me know your ideas.

```
declare @EmployeeStartDate datetime='01-Sep-2013'
declare @EmployeeEndDate datetime='15-Nov-2013'
select DateDiff(mm,@EmployeeStartDate, DateAdd(mm, 1,@EmployeeEndDate))
```

Output = `3`
expected output = `2.5`

Since I have only 15 days in Nov, So I should get `0.5` for Nov

Comment: You miss-placed `dd` instead of `MM`

Comment: If @EmployeeEndDate datetime='08-Nov-2013' What will be the result expected ?

Comment: It should be 2.2 .... 8th Nov ( 8/30=0.2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,'2013-09-01', '2013-11-15')>30 THEN DATEDIFF(d,'2013-09-01', '2013-11-15')/30.0 ELSE 0 END AS 'MonthDifference'
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2013-09-01', '2013-11-15') / 30.436875E
```

Answer (score 2):

DateDiff compares the values of the column you specify to work out the difference, it doesn't compare both dates and give you an exact difference. You've told it to compare the Month values, so thats all it's looking it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

The Technet article details the return value of the DateDiff Function - note that it's only int.

If you want the value as an exact figure (or nearabouts), you should datediff the dates on days, then divide by 30. For neatness, I've also rounded to a single decimal place.

```
select Round(Convert(decimal, DateDiff(dd,@EmployeeStartDate, @EmployeeEndDate)) / 30, 1)
```

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti Thanks, yeah I was in the process of writing that up as you commented. Great minds...

Answer (score 2):

```
select CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDate) AS float) -
  (DATEPART(dd,StartDate)*1.0 - 1.0) / DAY(EOMONTH(StartDate)) +
  ((DATEPART(dd,EndDate)*1.0 ) / DAY(EOMONTH(EndDate)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
declare @EmployeeStartDate datetime='01-Sep-2013'
declare @EmployeeEndDate datetime='15-Nov-2013'

;WITH cDayDiff AS
(
   select DateDiff(dd,@EmployeeStartDate, DateAdd(dd, 1,@EmployeeEndDate)) as days
)
SELECT
   CAST(days as float) / 30  as Months
FROM
   cDayDiff
```

It has `76` days which equals to `2.5333`

Output:

```
Months
============
2.53333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, none of the other answers take into account that not all months are exactly 30 days long.

This is what I came up with:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '07-Oct-2018'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '06-Nov-2018'
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(m, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    + 1.0 * DAY(@EndDate) / DAY(EOMONTH(@EndDate))
    - 1.0 * DAY(@StartDate) / DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDate))

-- 0.974193548388
```

The formula can be explained like this:

1. The difference in months as output by `DATEDIFF(m, ..., ...)`
2. Plus the day of the last date divided by the number of days in that month
3. Minus the day of the first date divided by the number of days in that month

Note that in this case the answer from Ren Yuzhi gives the result 1.006451612904. The `1.0` is necessary to make the division happen in floating point rather than integer.

Comment: Still doesn't work with these dates: 08-Jan-2019 - 08-Feb-2019

Comment: You're right. This is harder than I first imagined. What do we want to output for dates 30-jan-2019 -> 28-feb-2019??

Comment: I suppose, I'm not even sure. We struggled quite a bit with this issue and came up with the solution: construct a new DateTime object with a hardcoded 1 as the day and then subtract 1 day, that way you always get the last day of the month.

Comment: Doesn't work for Feb but this is pretty dang close. I'm trying to replicate `lubridate::interval()` from R

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @EmployeeStartDate datetime='013-09-01'
declare @EmployeeEndDate datetime='2013-11-15'
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, @EmployeeStartDate, @EmployeeEndDate)
```

Thanks for this.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Answer (score -2):

You can use Below to calculate the No Of Months between two Dates in MySQL,

```
PERIOD_DIFF(concat(year(Date1),LPAD(month(Date1),2,0)),concat(year(Date2),LPAD(month(Date2),2,0)))
```