# Select second latest date for each group in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi guys for a report I need to find the second latest date for every specific SKU

down below is the code I am working with.
this is a simplified example.

```
SKU  |  plannendstartinflow
11538   2015-03-12
11538   2016-03-12
11538   2017-03-12
33252   2018-02-17
```

what i need to become is this because it is the second latest date of that SKU

```
SKU  | plannendstartinflow
11538  2016-03-12
```

code below is the code that is used right now for the latest date
update :

```
  select * from 
(select 
case when DATEDIFF(MONTH,MAX(PlannedEndInflow),GETDATE()) > 3 then max(PlannedEndInflow) else null  end as datum
--case when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,od.PlannedEndInflow,Max(od.PlannedEndInflow)) > 1 then max(od.PlannedEndInflow) else null end as test
,od.odscheduleid
,lc.shortname as line
,ar.erpcode as SKU
,ar.shortname as Article
,od.PlannedEndInflow
,od.[PlannedEndInflow] as second_max_date
,Max(od.PlannedEndInflow) as max_date 
,st.shortname as 'status'
,od.[ShortName] as 'order'
,od.[ERPCode]
,od.[ASCode]
,od.[PlannedQuantity] as 'PlannedQuantity [PC]'
,cast(od.[PlannedQuantity]*ar.Volume/100 as decimal(12,2)) as 'PlannedQuantity [HL]'
,od.[PlannedChangeoverTime]
,od.[PlannedSpeed]
,od.[PlannedSpeedRatio],
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ar.erpcode order by od.PlannedEndInflow desc) as rn 
from(

    [RM].[TblDatODSchedule] od

  inner join [EM].[TblLstLocation] lc on od.locationid=lc.locationid
  inner join [RM].[TblLstART] ar on od.artid=ar.artid
  inner join [EM].[TblLstStatus] st on od.statusid=st.statusid


     )
      --where lc.shortname = 'lb1' and PlannedEndOutflow > '20190101'


      group by 
       ar.ERPCode , lc.ShortName,od.odscheduleid,ar.shortname 
,od.[PlannedStartInflow]
,od.[PlannedEndInflow]
,st.shortname
,od.[ShortName] 
,od.[ERPCode]
,od.[ASCode]
,od.[PlannedQuantity]
,ar.Volume
,od.[PlannedChangeoverTime]
,od.[PlannedSpeed]
,od.[PlannedSpeedRatio]
) t2 where rn=2;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the second latest date:

```
select * from 
(select SKU,plannendstartinflow,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by SKU order by plannendstartinflow desc) as rn 
from test
)t where rn=2;
```

EDIT:

```
select * from 
(select SKU,plannendstartinflow,  --similarly add other columns
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by SKU order by plannendstartinflow desc) as rn 
from (
      --Put Your Subquery here
     )t1
)t2 where rn=2;
```

EDIT2: To select max and second max date.

```
select SKU,min(plannendstartinflow) as secondmaxdate,max(plannendstartinflow) as 
maxdate from 
(select * from (select SKU,plannendstartinflow,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by SKU order by plannendstartinflow desc) as rn 
from test
)t where rn<3
)t1 group by SKU;
```

Comment: and how would you implement that in my code without compromising the working of it ?

Comment: hi Navreen , thanks this is working for the second highest date is there anyway i also can show the highest date without this code overwriting it when i try MAX() the code will change that back to the second highest date ?

Comment: If you want to display different rows for highest date and second highest date then you simply change `rn=2` to `rn<3`. And if you want to display different columns then you should use `CASE`.

Comment: what i try to do is compare the highest with the second highest date if there is a 3 month difference I need to show the highest date. how can i do this when the MAX(date) is overwritten by the code above. sorry for all the questions :)

Comment: Use `case` and select both the dates highest and second highest in different columns and then use `DATEDIFF`. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677122/month-difference-between-two-dates-in-sql-server

Comment: but how do i select the highest date ? with your code everything in that column is the second highest date ? so "plannendendinflow is now every second highest date but now i also need the highest of the "plannendinflow" and then compare these 2 , i have no clue how to do this ?

Comment: hi navreen check my updated code. your latest solution for max and second does not seem to work ?